# Remove time from date in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, report, cognos-8

I am working with Cognos Reporting Studio. What I'm trying to do is to dispaly a count of items that fall in a range of dates. I am to display the counts for the year selected and the two previous years. But there is a fourth count being displayed with a blank year. Now I have come to think that this is becasue of then time attached to the date. So when the max date value is Mar 1, 2013 12:00:00AM, then Mar 1, 2013 06:17:00AM falls outside of that range. I need to remove the time from the dates. Here is what I'm currently using:

```
Case

when [GCR_RECEIVED_DT] between cast(substring ([FromDate],1,10),date) 
and _add_years(cast(substring ([ToDate],1,10),date),-2) 
then extract(year, _add_years([ToDate],-2) )

when [GCR_RECEIVED_DT] between _add_years(cast(substring ([FromDate],1,10),date),1)
and _add_years(cast(substring ([ToDate],1,10),date),-1) 
then extract(year,_add_years([ToDate],-1))

when [GCR_RECEIVED_DT] between _add_years(cast(substring ([FromDate],1,10),date),2)
and cast(substring ([ToDate],1,10),date) 
then extract(year,[ToDate])

end
```

I was told that I should use cast and substring. But I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions'
>   status='-9'.

Along with this big message. I'm sure I don't have to include all of this, but I'm going to.

> UDA-SQL-0107 A general exception has occurred during the operation
>   "prepare".ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier RSV-SRV-0042
>   Trace back:RSReportService.cpp(722): QFException: CCL_CAUGHT:
>   RSReportService::process()RSReportServiceMethod.cpp(263): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSReportServiceMethod::process():
>   asynchWait_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(808): QFException:
>   RSASyncExecutionThread::checkExceptionRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(260):
>   QFException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSASyncExecutionThread::runImpl():
>   promptPagingForward_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(864):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: RSASyncExecutionThread::processCommand():
>   promptPagingForward_RequestExecution/RSRenderExecution.cpp(670):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSRenderExecution::executeAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(291):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSLayoutAssembly.cpp(79):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSLayoutAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSReportPagesAssembly.cpp(179):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSReportPagesAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSPageAssembly.cpp(303):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSPageAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableRowAssembly.cpp(177):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableRowAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableCellAssembly.cpp(137):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableCellAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSTableAssembly.cpp(119):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSTableRowAssembly.cpp(177):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableRowAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableCellAssembly.cpp(137):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableCellAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyRSQueryMgr.cpp(1131):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::getResultSetIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1295): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::createIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1569):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgr.cpp(1559): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(168):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(160):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()QFSSession.cpp(1147):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1145): QFException:
>   CCL_CAUGHT: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1102):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1078): QFException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSConnection.cpp(788):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSConnection::ExecuteQFSQuery.cpp(213):
>   QFException: CCL_RETHROW: QFSQuery::Execute
>   v2CoordinationQFSQuery.cpp(4456): QFException: CCL_THROW:
>   CoordinationPlanner

I've also tried to_date instead of cast. But I still get the same thing. Any help?

Comment: Try to break it down, there is way too much going on in there to troubleshoot.  See if you can get some individual pieces of it to work, like substring ([FromDate],1,10), then expand it to cast(substring ([FromDate],1,10),date), etc.

Comment: Are there restrictions on what substring can be used with? It seems to only work with my DatePrompt values, not with my DataItems.

Comment: thank you for your help. the issue turned out to have a very simple fix.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  However, I think Oracle uses substr, not substring.  Don't know if that will matter or not.

Comment: i tried substr when i got the error. it still wouldn't work. but i figured out a simple fix. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used _add_days with my ToDate so the max date is now Mar 2, 2013 12:00:00AM. This alows cognos to count the Mar 1, 2013 dates properly.